# Changing the dropdown value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I was able to change the selected value of the dropdownlist but it submits the form once i changed it.

Once I clicked this button:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn-warning btn-sm" value="@ViewBag.devIdLoggin" onclick="FunctionClicked(this);">Assign to me</button>
</div>
```

I should change the selected value of this dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DevId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'll have this script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FunctionClicked(obj)
    {
        obj.preventDefault;
        var value = obj.value;
        document.getElementById("DevId").onselect(value);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

How could I change the selected value of the dropdown without submitting the form?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Use `<button type="button" .... >`

Comment: I have tried adding the type="button" and now, it's not changing the value.

Comment: I don't see how you code (`.onselect`) could have changed anything. Use `<button type="button" id="update" data-id=""@ViewBag.devIdLoggin" class="btn-warning btn-sm">Assign to me</button>` and then `$('#update').click(function(){ $('#DevId').val($(this).data('id')); });`

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke